# Determine image size of text drawn with ImageMagick?

Tags: imagemagick

I'd like to generate some font-effects using `convert` but don't see an easy way to calculate a canvas size. The method I have now is to generate the text as desired, such as `convert label:ABCDEF` then load the resulting image to get its size. This seems highly inefficient and troublesome.

Is there a command option or method to simply calculate the metrics of the resulting text?

Answer (score 1):

the best solution I actually see is:

```
convert -verbose label:ABCDEF png:- >/dev/null
```

which results in the following message on stderr:

```
label:ABCDEF=>ABCDEF LABEL 53x15 53x15+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 0.020u 0:00.010
```

The requested size is in column 3: 53x15

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the text metrics a bit more directly, though leu's size option is also good. Using the `-debug annotate` option you can then search for the `Metrics:` output which includes the text size.